# Graphing multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, graphing

I am having trouble plotting some data in R. I have 3 conditions which I want to plot plus a control.

I managed to to plot my conditions separately using the ggpubr:

```
    data2 <- read.csv("/data)

    library(ggpubr)

ggpaired(data = data2, cond1 = "Untreated", cond2 = "A", fill = "condition", palette = "jco")

ggpaired(data = data2, cond1 = "A", cond2 = "B", fill = "condition", palette = "jco")

ggpaired(data = data2, cond1 = "B", cond2 = "Both", fill = "condition", palette = "jco")
```

This produces graphs like so:

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

[image: Graph 4]

[image: Graph 5]

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can plot all 4 conditions together so there are interconnecting lines between each point?

Also, I wondered if anyone knew any packages or functions where I can just plot values but without a box plot?

Thanks

Kurtis.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a case of data arrangement and using facet_grid to separate the plots.
You could also look into cowplot and arrange the plots in the order you like. It can auto label the top as A, B... making it easy to refer in the description

Comment: Thanks! I did think about arranging them however, since the conditions are nominal (we should see a dose-dependent response) I wanted a way to plot all 4 variables together with interconnecting lines. So untreated - A - B - Both